# Wordpress can't load styles: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to convert HTML static website to WordPress. I'm stuck at the very beginning, where I need to load all my styles from css folder in my *function.php*

```
<?php 
// Loading styles

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles' );
function load_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome2.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'framework', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/framework.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . 'style.css' );
}

?>
```

Here are all my files located in the following directory:

[image]

And then I'm trying to inspect element in Google Chrome I got a bunch of errors that are saying the same thing: *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

In my *header.php* I'm calling `<?php wp_head(); ?>` right before the `</head>` TAG. In my *index.php* file I'm calling `<?php get_header(); ?>`

I tried to move `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_styles' );` to the bottom;

I tried to set permissions for my folders in Filezilla to 777;

I tried to use `get_stylesheet_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`;

And I don't know what I supposed to do next.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but have you activated the theme?

Comment: Just check through the browser source code and check with the css url, i think that it's not correct one. it's the easy way to get URL and check through the source code.

Comment: Yes I have activated my custom theme in the WordPress dashboard. I'm able to see my markup without styles.

Comment: Are the URLs set correctly in Settings >> General?

Comment: I mean I deleted my old stylesheets that were from old HTML file in the header.php and it seems like it started to load them. I've also forgot to add '/' before style.css in the wp_enqueue_style. Thank you all for the help and VERY quick responses :).

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already figured this out but it looks like you missed `/css/` before your style.css

It should look something like this:

`wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );`